# Laravel toSql does not exists after flatten()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here my code :

```
            $cards = Course::with('cards', 'cards.contexts', 'cards.user_contexts', 'cards.thisUser')
                ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. 'Kanji' .'%')
                ->get()
                ->pluck('cards')
                ->flatten()
                ->toSql();

            dd($cards);
```

I try to get the SQL code of my eloquent request.

I get this error :

> "Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::toSql does not exist."

Anyone have an idea of the problem ? Thanks !

Comment: Because after calling `get()` the query is already executed and a collection is returned with which `pluck()` continues

Comment: Thanks, so, there is no way to get the sql code like this ?

Comment: You can either get it before calling `get()`, need to rewrite your code (`pluck()` could be used before calling `get()`) or you need to dump something other than SQL.

Comment: You can see these options in my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67738617/7451109

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because after calling `get()` the query is already executed and a collection is returned with which `pluck()` continues. You have some other possibilities:

1. Rewrite your statement to use `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::pluck()` instead of  `Illuminate\Support\Collection::pluck()` but without `flatten()`

   ```
   $cards = Course::with('cards', 'cards.contexts', 'cards.user_contexts', 'cards.thisUser')
                   ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. 'Kanji' .'%')
                   ->pluck('cards')
                   ->get()
                   ->toSql();

               dd($cards);
   ```
2. Call `toSql()` directly on the query and omit `pluck()` and `flatten()`

   ```
   $cards = Course::with('cards', 'cards.contexts', 'cards.user_contexts', 'cards.thisUser')
                   ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. 'Kanji' .'%')
                   ->get()
                   ->toSql();

               dd($cards);
   ```
3. Dump something other than SQL → the collection instead

   ```
   $cards = Course::with('cards', 'cards.contexts', 'cards.user_contexts', 'cards.thisUser')
                   ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. 'Kanji' .'%')
                   ->get()
                   ->pluck('cards')
                   ->flatten();

               dd($cards);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can use db enable query log

```
 DB::enableQueryLog();
    
    $data = $order->all();
    
       $cards = Course::with('cards', 'cards.contexts', 'cards.user_contexts', 'cards.thisUser')
                    ->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'. 'Kanji' .'%')
                    ->get()
                    ->pluck('cards')
                    ->flatten();
    $query = DB::getQueryLog();
    dd($query);
```